# How to make filter queryset for a model having a many to many attribute for multiple values in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Description :- I want to filter all the Entry whose authors are john & paul. Below are my models that I am using. Can anyone solve this question:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def str__(self):              # unicode__ on Python 2
     return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     email = models.EmailField()

     def str__(self):              # unicode__ on Python 2
       return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
     blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
     headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     body_text = models.TextField()
     pub_date = models.DateField()
     mod_date = models.DateField()
     authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
     n_comments = models.IntegerField()
     n_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
     rating = models.IntegerField()

    def str__(self):              # unicode__ on Python 2
      return self.headline
```

Comment: `Entry.objects.filter(authors__in=[Author.objects.get(name='John'),Author.objects.get(name='Paul')]).distinct()`

Comment: This is not possible.We want all such entries where both authors are there.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid why you marked question as already existing.If it is already existing you can give correct answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter twice (as @dnit13 says). Its only way

```
Entry.objects.all().filter(authors__name='john').filter(authors__name='paul')
```

If list of authors is dynamic:

```
authors = ['john', 'paul']
entries = Entry.objects.all()
for author in authors:
    entries = entries.filter(authors__name=author)
```

Comment: I have tried this approach but still we won't get all such entries where both authors are there.

Answer (score 0):

Just use filter twice

```
Entry.objects.filter(authors__name='john').filter(authors__name='paul')
```

Comment: I do not prefer this way as if there will be more author then our query would be very long.So we need some other concrete way to solve such queries.But still thanks for the answer.

Comment: The other way is to use Q objects, which I doubt it will work for this scenario

Comment: Q objects won't work here as it is mainly for using complex query with OR operations.